# What is the correct way to write this PowerShell IF condition that tests if a URL exists in a SharePoint list

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I've provided a script below that populates an SPO list with hubsites and associated sites. I've written a line near the bottom that should stop it from writing anymore lines if the `SiteUrl` is matched:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://myCompany-admin.sharepoint.com" -Interactive
$Report = @()
Write-Host "Getting list of all hubsites..."
$HubSites = Get-PnPHubSite
Write-Host "Getting list of all sites excluding sites without a connected hub..."
$Sites = Get-PnPTenantSite | ? {$_.HubSiteId.Guid -ne "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
Write-Host "Getting the target SPO site to create items..."
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/HubSiteMap" -Interactive
$List = Get-PnPList "Sites" -Connection $connection
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $List

ForEach($Hub in $HubSites)
{
    # Get the ID of the Hubsite
    $HubSiteId = $Hub.ID.GUID
    # Iterate through each site collection
    ForEach($Site in $Sites)
    {
        # Get the Associated Hubsite ID for this site
        $AssociatedHubSiteID = $Site.HubSiteId.Guid
        If ( ($AssociatedHubSiteID -eq $HubSiteId) -and ($Hub.SiteUrl -ne $Site.Url) )
        {
            $ReportEntry = "" | Select-Object Hub,SiteUrl 
            $ReportEntry.Hub = $Hub.SiteUrl 
            $ReportEntry.SiteUrl = $Site.Url
            $Report += $ReportEntry        
            if ($Site.Url -notin $ListItems.FieldValuesAsText.SiteUrl) { #THIS LINE IS NOT WORKING!
                Add-PnPListItem -List $List -Values @{"Hub" = $Hub.SiteUrl; "SiteUrl" = $Site.Url}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The SPO list has two single line text columns `Hub` and `SiteUrl`

Comment: If you want the inner `foreach` loop to stop once the condition of your second `if` statement is matched, you could add a `break` statement in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PnP PowerShell script like this:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://myCompany-admin.sharepoint.com" -Interactive
$Report = @()
Write-Host "Getting list of all hubsites..."
$HubSites = Get-PnPHubSite
Write-Host "Getting list of all sites excluding sites without a connected hub..."
$Sites = Get-PnPTenantSite | ? {$_.HubSiteId.Guid -ne "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
Write-Host "Getting the target SPO site to create items..."
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/HubSiteMap" -Interactive
$List = Get-PnPList "Sites" -Connection $connection

ForEach($Hub in $HubSites)
{
    # Get the ID of the Hubsite
    $HubSiteId = $Hub.ID.GUID
    # Iterate through each site collection
    ForEach($Site in $Sites)
    {
        # Get the Associated Hubsite ID for this site
        $AssociatedHubSiteID = $Site.HubSiteId.Guid
        If ( ($AssociatedHubSiteID -eq $HubSiteId) -and ($Hub.SiteUrl -ne $Site.Url) )
        {
            $ReportEntry = "" | Select-Object Hub,SiteUrl 
            $ReportEntry.Hub = $Hub.SiteUrl 
            $ReportEntry.SiteUrl = $Site.Url
            $Report += $ReportEntry     

            # Check if list item with SiteUrl exists   
            $getListItem = Get-PnPListItem -List $List -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='SiteUrl'/><Value Type='Text'>$($Site.Url)</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"

            if($getListItem) {
                Write-Host "Site Url $($Site.Url) already exists in the list."
            }
            else {
                Add-PnPListItem -List $List -Values @{"Hub" = $Hub.SiteUrl; "SiteUrl" = $Site.Url}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `SiteUrl` is the internal name of your text column in the list. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: [try avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is ineffective.